# Is there a way to know when "everyone" is done with a message in masstransit?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asynchronous, masstransit

I have a Web.API and Angular app that works great.. However there is one hitch.. The app integrates several different systems in a fairly complex (but fast) workflow and the challenge I have, is when I kick it off, I don't really know when its over, and as such, sometimes the screen updates appropriately when the async call is finished, and sometimes the process is still going and the refresh shows stale data.

I was wondering if there was a way in MassTransit (other than a PublishRequest) that I could "monitor" a specific message and know when all of its consumers are in fact done with it?

I have a few ideas around listening for a "completed" message to bounce back, but that seems pretty noisy if there are 10 or 20,000 users... and turning everything into a Request, just so I can get a response seems equally wasteful..

I'm all ears,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple options, on the mailing list I think there's been some discussion about this in the past as well.

1. Use Signalr to notify the UI when a complete event happens. There's a RabbitMQ Backplane and I've heard this works pretty awesomely in some case.
2. Do Request/Response and wait for the response for each message
3. Do Request/Response but request out to a Saga that does all the work and then responds when it hits the right state. I've never tried to tie that together, so might be slightly tricky, but totally doable.
4. Create a Saga that will respond to status messages, so your UI can ping it directly via Request/Response to get updates. Depending on how you back the data for the Saga, you can also query your data store for the Saga to get statuses. The NHibernate Saga Repository for example would let you just hit DB tables to get status.

There might be some other options, but nothing is initially coming to mind that isn't going to be really complicated. I'd suggest joining the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss) if you want to dig into this further because some of the people there have experience building out similar stuff. I've just done the last one.